# Not able to build web project when weblgic server is running

Tags: eclipse, weblogic, weblogic12c

Recently I upgraded to Weblogic 12. Now when I try to build the project it always says:

[INFO] Deleting C:\MyPrjectWorkspace\MyWebProject\target

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

I have to stop the server, then build and then start and then deploy again.
It was working fine with WLS10.

Any idea how to get rid of stopping the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if that is the problem. In Weblogic console (Optional Settings)
 when I deploy the application, earlier it was selected as "I will make the deployment accessible from the following location". After I change it to "Copy this application onto every target for me" it worked for me. Now I can build the project in eclipse when the server is up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps :

1. Create a new Workspace.
2. Add your server.
3. Migrate your code.
4. Clean build your code.
5. Start server.
6. Deploy your code.
7. Run your code.
8. Make changes in your code and do a clean build and see if its working.

Comment: In that case I think you need to un-install and then re-install your IDE .. eclipse or anything else. And then re-do your code. Don't copy the .settings folder in new workspace in new installation. Its very hard to re-produce your scenario.